# My WooCommerce shop Search Results page's breadcrumb shows "woocommerce-placeholder", how do I remove that?

Tags: woocommerce

In my WooCommerce shop, when I do a Search, the breadcrumb says "Home > woocommerce-placeholder > Search results for “searchterm”.

I'm using the default **storefront** theme.

How do I remove "woocommerce-placeholder"?

And when I click it in the breadcrumb, it actually goes to "mysite.com/woocommerce-placeholder/" and shows all my products. What's going on?

Comment: **woocommerce-placeholder** could be your shop page title/slug. You can goto pages and check which page is set as Shop/Store page.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your permalinks.

`Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > Save Changes`

I have heard times where permalinks do not refresh fully unless you save twice so I would save twice just for good measure.

Comment: Hmm, no luck on that :(

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this same problem with the storefront Theme.
Go to the Status page on Woocommerce,
scroll down till you find that page listed,
click on it
it will bring you to a generic page with a placeholder image,
Change the name to Whatever you want to appear in the breadcrumb,
then go to settings, products and change the store page to 'shop' or whatever your actual store is called.
the first steps are in case of any redirects i've not covered. the last one is what actually changes the landing page for your store.